# "Ext.getCmp(...) is undefined" in different function

Tags: extjs, get, undefined, return-value

I have Extjs code in view, this is it:

```
createPanelMC: function() {
        this.requiredSign = '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>';
        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            name: 'nodebPanel',
            width: '100%',
            layout: {
                type: 'auto',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype   : 'fieldset', 
                name    : 'modlayanan',
                title   : 'Data Pelanggan',
                layout  : 'column',
                width   : '95%',
                margin  : '10',
                items: [{
                    xtype           : 'textfield',
                    name            : 'nomor',
                    id              : 'nomor',
                    fieldLabel      : 'PSTN',
                    emptyText       : 'Nomor...',
                    margin          : '10 0 0 0',
                    width           : 350,
                    labelWidth      : 100,
                    afterLabelTextTpl: this.requiredSign    
                }, {
                    xtype           : 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel      : 'Speedy',
                    name            : 'speedy',
                    id              : 'speedy',
                    margin          : '10 0 10 20',
                    width           : 350,
                    labelWidth      : 100
                },
                this.createTreePaketExist()
                ]
            }],
            dockedItems: [ {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    name: 'tbpaketmc',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    items: [ {
                            text: '<< Back',
                            action: 'doBack'
                        },'->', {
                            text: 'Submit',
                            action: 'doSubmit'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        return panel;
    },
```

i call `nomor` dan `speedy` in `this.createTreePaketExist()` . This is the `this.createTreePaketExist()` code:

```
createTreePaketExist: function() {
        var nopstn= Ext.getCmp('nomor').getValue();
        var speedy= Ext.getCmp('speedy').getValue();
        var storeTree = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'data/newoss_get_paket.php',
                params: { 
                        nopstn:nopstn
                        ,speedy:speedy
                }
            }
        });

    var groupProduct = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        store       : storeTree,
        name        : 'treeProduct',
        rootVisible : false,
        useArrows   : true,
        layout      :'fit',
        margin      : '0 0 0 0',
        autoScroll  : true,
        height      : 150,
        width       : '93%',
        listeners: 
        {
            checkchange: function(node, checked, eOpts){
                 node.eachChild(function(n) {
                node.cascadeBy(function(n){
                    n.set('checked', checked);
                });
            });
            p = node.parentNode;
            var pChildCheckedCount = 0;
            p.suspendEvents();
            p.eachChild(function(c) { 
                if (c.get('checked')) pChildCheckedCount++; 
                    p.set('checked', !!pChildCheckedCount);
                });
            p.resumeEvents();
            }
        }
    });
    return groupProduct; 
},
```

but it gave an error: `Ext.getCmp(...) is undefined`. Help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createTreePaketExist` will be called during component initialisation, it's unlikely the textfields are actually rendered or even initialised properly at this point, best to use the listeners. You could use [refs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs) in your controller to get a reference to these fields automatically or you could listen to the [afterrender](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-event-afterrender) event and then reference the fields.

I have created a fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h5o) that shows how to load the store on form submit, you could also do this on the textfield's change events.

Here is the code for reference:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            name: 'nodebPanel',
            width: '100%',
            layout: {
                type: 'auto',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                name: 'modlayanan',
                title: 'Data Pelanggan',
                layout: 'column',
                width: '95%',
                margin: '10',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'nomor',
                    id: 'nomor',
                    fieldLabel: 'PSTN',
                    emptyText: 'Nomor...',
                    margin: '10 0 0 0',
                    width: 350,
                    labelWidth: 100,
                    afterLabelTextTpl: this.requiredSign
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Speedy',
                    name: 'speedy',
                    id: 'speedy',
                    margin: '10 0 10 20',
                    width: 350,
                    labelWidth: 100
                }]
            }],
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                name: 'tbpaketmc',
                dock: 'bottom',
                items: [{
                    text: '<< Back',
                    action: 'doBack'
                }, '->', {
                    text: 'Submit',
                    action: 'doSubmit',
                    bindForm: true,
                    handler: function() {
                        var nopstn = Ext.getCmp('nomor').getValue();
                        var speedy = Ext.getCmp('speedy').getValue();

                        if (nopstn != '' && speedy != '') {
                            var store = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#treeProduct')[0].getStore();
                            console.log(store);
                            store.load({
                                params: {
                                    nopstn: nopstn,
                                    speedy: speedy
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });

        var storeTree = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'data/newoss_get_paket.php'
            }
        });

        var groupProduct = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            store: storeTree,
            itemId: 'treeProduct',
            name: 'treeProduct',
            rootVisible: false,
            useArrows: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            margin: '0 0 0 0',
            autoScroll: true,
            height: 150,
            width: '93%',
            listeners: {
                checkchange: function(node, checked, eOpts) {
                    node.eachChild(function(n) {
                        node.cascadeBy(function(n) {
                            n.set('checked', checked);
                        });
                    });
                    p = node.parentNode;
                    var pChildCheckedCount = 0;
                    p.suspendEvents();
                    p.eachChild(function(c) {
                        if (c.get('checked')) pChildCheckedCount++;
                        p.set('checked', !! pChildCheckedCount);
                    });
                    p.resumeEvents();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, i made `getValue` function in controller with `refs` , but i don't know how to pass it into treepanel in view..

Comment: Use afterrender listener, make sure your trying to get the field when it's rendered, not before

Comment: I'll create a fiddle shortly, I need to know one thing beforehand though... where does nomar and speedy get their data from? does the user enter it?

Comment: It looks like your asking pretty much the same question across three different questions, you should consider closing any duplicates or making your other questions more specific before that are closed down. [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145642/cant-send-parameter-ajax-in-extjs), [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162633/pass-or-send-data-from-controller-to-view-extjs) and of course this one.

Comment: ok, i deleted one of questions. but, can it show without click submit before, like autoload? @Scriptable

Comment: can I add render to fieldset or panel? @Scriptable

Comment: Yes, you could do this on panel render, form or field focus or even as the user fills out the information

Comment: could you tell me an event to make handler on panel? i tried handler but it can't @Scriptable

Comment: you could just attach to the fields themselves [see here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-event-specialkey), the listeners are the same, just move them to wherever you need them

Comment: yes,it can.. may i ask again? @Scriptable can it just show like autoload .. without click the field first?

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.getCmp()` is **not recommended** to use in ExtJS code. Instead you should use

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#nomor')
```

Where *nomor* is id of element.

But **To resolve** your problem try to call this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name="nomor"]')
```

or

```
Ext.getCmp('#nomor')
```

if this **will not help** you then the problem in your code structure. May be piece of code that represents *getCmp('nomor')* is loaded and invoked before piece of code that represents your *nomor* code. This problem may occur if you do not use **MVC**

Comment: would it get the value? cause i tried but it's still null @Almas

Comment: Try to do this:
1) open you browser and open your app
2) let the app to be loaded fully
3) open your browser command line (in Chrome Ctrl+Shift+J)
4) Try to write Ext.getCmp('#nomor') and then press Enter
5) if you have nothing try with Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name="nomor"]')

I believe there will be some result that is output. If so your code were incorrectly loaded. this is your problem i think

Comment: but do you see nomor component for example? was it rendered to browser?