# Can't Send Parameter Ajax in ExtJs

Tags: php, ajax, extjs, parameters

I have code in View Extjs. Here's the code:

```
var storeTree = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'data/newoss_get_paket.php',
                params: { nopstn:"02318330549",
                        num:"tester"
                }
            }
        });
```

I call it in newoss_get_paket.php:

```
$pstn = $_POST['nopstn']; 
$number= $_POST['num'];
```

But the result is null.. parameters can't sent to php file. any solution for me?

Comment: writer: {
                type: 'json'
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [extraParams config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-extraParams) instead of `params`. There is no `params` config on a proxy.